# Recv or send in winsock2 are not sending data

Tags: c++, winapi, server, winsock2

I am trying to learn how to build servers. When trying to send data from my client app to the server app, the server app does not receive any data. I assume it is just because of my lack of knowledge on the char buffer I'm sending. The client is able to join on the server and the server does register the client.

SERVER:

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include<windows.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include<ws2tcpip.h>
#include<iphlpapi.h>


#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#define PORT "69"
#define BUFFLEN 512



int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    bool active = true;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    struct addrinfo* result = NULL, * ptr = NULL, hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    std::cout << "which port should be initialized?\n>>>";
    std::string input; 
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cout << "initializing..." << std::endl;
    getaddrinfo(NULL, input.c_str(), &hints, &result);



    SOCKET listenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    listenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    bind(listenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    freeaddrinfo(result);

    listen(listenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    std::cout << "initialized" << std::endl;

    //accept connection
    std::cout << "waiting for client..." << std::endl;
    SOCKET clientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    clientSocket = accept(listenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    std::cout << "client connected" << std::endl;

    char recvBuf[100];
    int dataRes;
    std::cout << "TERMINAL:" << std::endl;
    while (active) {
        dataRes = recv(clientSocket, recvBuf, 100, 0);
        if (dataRes > 0) {
            if (recvBuf == "terminate")
                active = false;
            else
                std::cout << "CLIENT:" << recvBuf << std::endl;
        }
    }

    shutdown(clientSocket, SD_SEND);
    closesocket(clientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

CLIENT:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>


// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "69"

int __cdecl main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo* result = NULL,
    * ptr = NULL,
    hints;
    const char* sendbuf = "this is a test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    std::cout << "enter ip address\n>>>";
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(input.c_str(), DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
             ptr->ai_protocol);

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
         printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
         WSACleanup();
         return 1;
    }


    //iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    bool serverActive = true;
    while (serverActive) {
        char inp[100];
        std::cin >> inp;
        std::cout << "SENT:" << inp << std::endl;
        send(ConnectSocket, inp, (int)strlen(inp), 0);

        if (inp == "terminate")
            serverActive = false;
    }


   // cleanup
   closesocket(ConnectSocket);
   WSACleanup();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Same story as always. All of the socket functions you are calling on the server `WSAStartup`, `getaddrinfo`, `socket`, `bind`, `listen`, `accept` etc. etc. return error codes if they fail. Check each and everyone of them for a failure. If any of them are that gives you a clue as to what is wrong. If none of them are returning an error code that gives you a different clue as to what might be wrong. When dealing with the external world, never assume that function calls are going to succeed, sometimes they don't.

Comment: Did you really mean to call `shutdown` on the client before you sent anything? That obviously explains why it isn't working. Had you checked the return code from `send` you probably would have detected this.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. When I am trying to learn a new area of win32, I try to declutter the code so I can understand everything. In the process I removed error checking. In hindsight I can tell that it is a bad idea to do that.